# ZIO interop with Cats on parallel operations

Tags: scala, zio

`ZIO` is not dependent on `Cats`, so it has its own methods to perform `sequence` operations:  `ZIO.sequencePar` and `ZIO.sequence`.

I tried to use `sequence` provided by interop with `Cats` and it works the same way as `ZIO.sequence`:

```
import zio._
import zio.interop.catz._
import cats.implicits._ 

val t1: Task[Int] =  ???
val t2: Task[Int] =  ???
val t3: Task[Int] =  ???

val seq = List(t1,t2,t3).sequence // <-- t1,t2,t3 are executed sequentially 

(new DefaultRuntime {}).unsafeRun(seq)
```

Can I make `ZIO` treat `sequence` as `ZIO.sequencePar`, so I could run tasks in parallel?

It seems that `ZIO` needs some implementation of parallel `Traverse` for `Cats`, but I can't find any.

Here are my dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "dev.zio" %% "zio" % "1.0.0-RC10-1"
libraryDependencies += "dev.zio" %% "zio-interop-cats" % "2.0.0.0-RC1"
```

**Edit:**

With help of @AndreyTyukin I found that to make it works in parallel I need to run `List(k,k2,k3).parSequence` which use instance of typeclass `Parallel` available in `zio-interop-cats` lib. And @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez 's comments for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166813/understanding-of-parallel-typeclass-from-cats) question give some explanation of why we have to use `Parallel`.