# Understanding of Parallel typeclass from Cats

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats

There is a typeclass called `Parallel` in `Cats`. The purpose of this class is to provide parallel computations for some monads that don't support parallel computations out of the box like `Either` for example.

I know that `Monad` is used for dependent computations and thus requires sequential execution. `Applicative` is used for independent computations, so such computations can be parallelized.

It's also known that each `Monad` is `Applicative` (monad is applicative functor).

So now I can't put together all concepts from the theory. If all monads are also applicatives, why I can't use applicative nature of monads for parallel computations and I need this `Parallel` typeclass?

Is it just an option for `Applicative` to support parallelism or it's a requirement?

Comment: Your understanding is almost correct, but you have a simple error. - _"Applicative is used for independent computations"_. That is not strictly true, an **Applicative** provides a mean to apply a function lifted on an `F` context to an effectual value. From that, you can derive a way to take two effectual values and return an effect of the tuple of the values, and that is it. On the other hand, a **Monad** takes that and adds the constraint of sequentiality, as such it guarantees that when creating the tuple, the first value will be evaluated first and then the second.

Comment: From that, one can conclude that an **Applicative** can be used to perform _"parallel"_ operations, whereas a **Monad** can not, because the **Monad** has the restriction to be sequential while the **Applicative** does not _(but it does not guarantee to be in parallel, for example it may also first evaluate the second and then the first, and still be valid)_. - Now, given that all **Monads** are also **Applicatives** means that you can implement all the abstract methods on the last using the ones of the former, but you still have to follow the **Monad** rules. Thus, it will be sequential.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for your explanation. Is it correct to say that `Either` monad implementation automatically provide non-parallel `Applicative`, but nothing stops us from implementing parallel `Applicative` for `Either` if we want?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez if so, then what are benefits of using `Parallel` typeclass in compare to implementing parallel `Applicative` in addition to `Monad`?

Comment: _"Well yes, but actually no"_ I am not sure if you can even implement a _"parallel"_ **Applicative** for `Either` _(I believe not, but lets suppose that yes)_. The problem is that, for the coherence, you should only have one instance of each **Typeclass** for each type. As such, you should not have two **Applicatives** for `Either` _(or for any effect)_. Thus, the use of **Parallel**, is to provide a new **Typeclass**, which is not related to neither **Applicative** nor **Monad** to provide those "parallel" operations to those effects that are **Monads** but can have a parallel **Applicative**

Comment: But going further, if you check the [scaladoc](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Parallel.html) of **Parallel**, you will see that it is parametric on two types `M` & `F` _(where `M` has a **Monad** and `F` has an **Applicative**)_ thus, it also covers cases when the **Monad** itself is not capable of doing "parallel" computations, but you can convert it into another effect which does. For example, take a look to the [instances](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/instances/ParallelInstances.html) of **Parallel**, you will see that for `Either` it goes to `Validated`.

Comment: Whereas for [**Ior**](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/Ior$.html) it uses itself for both, the **Monad** as well as the **Applicative**. - Thus, in this case, it does breaks the coherence principle, by creating a new **Applicative** that is "parallel". You can check that on the source code.

Comment: Luis that was a great explanation but it should have been an Answer rather than 7 comments :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, Ior does not break the coherence principle. It is indeed accumulating errors on `Ior.Both`, but not on `Ior.Left`.
See example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60400523/4296401 . 
`Ior` has its own Parallel Instance that will accumulate errors also on `Ior.Left` with the `par*` combinator family such as `parTraverse`, `parMapN`, etc.