# Scala Cats Accumulating Errors and Successes with Ior

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am trying to use Cats datatype Ior to accumulate both errors and successes of using a service (which can return an error).

```
def find(key: String): F[Ior[NonEmptyList[Error], A]] = {
  (for {
      b <- service.findByKey(key)
    } yield b.rightIor[NonEmptyList[Error]])
  .recover {
      case e: Error => Ior.leftNel(AnotherError)
    }
}

def findMultiple(keys: List[String]): F[Ior[NonEmptyList[Error], List[A]]] = {
  keys map find reduce (_ |+| _)
}
```

My confusion lies in how to combine the errors/successes. I am trying to use the Semigroup combine (infix syntax) to combine with no success. Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want both all errors and all successful results. Here's a possible implementation:

```scala
class Foo[F[_]: Applicative, A](find: String => F[IorNel[Error, A]]) {
  def findMultiple(keys: List[String]): F[IorNel[Error, List[A]]] = {
    keys.map(find).sequence.map { nelsList =>
      nelsList.map(nel => nel.map(List(_)))
        .reduceOption(_ |+| _).getOrElse(Nil.rightIor)
    }
  }
}
```

Let's break it down:

We will be trying to "flip" a `List[IorNel[Error, A]]` into `IorNel[Error, List[A]]`. However, from doing `keys.map(find)` we get `List[F[IorNel[...]]]`, so we need to also "flip" it in a similar fashion first. That can be done by using `.sequence` on the result, and is what forces `F[_]: Applicative` constraint.

N.B. `Applicative[Future]` is available whenever there's an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope. You can also get rid of `F` and use `Future.sequence` directly.

Now, we have `F[List[IorNel[Error, A]]]`, so we want to `map` the inner part to transform the `nelsList` we got. You might think that `sequence` could be used there too, but it can not - it has the "short-circuit on first error" behavior, so we'd lose all successful values. Let's try to use `|+|` instead.

`Ior[X, Y]` has a `Semigroup` instance when both `X` and `Y` have one. Since we're using `IorNel`, `X = NonEmptyList[Z]`, and that is satisfied. For `Y = A` - your domain type - it might not be available.

But we don't want to combine all results into a single `A`, we want `Y = List[A]` (which also always has a semigroup). So, we take every `IorNel[Error, A]` we have and `map` `A` to a singleton `List[A]`:

```
nelsList.map(nel => nel.map(List(_)))
```

This gives us `List[IorNel[Error, List[A]]`, which we can reduce. Unfortunately, since Ior does not have a `Monoid`, we can't quite use convenient syntax. So, with stdlib collections, one way is to do `.reduceOption(_ |+| _).getOrElse(Nil.rightIor)`.

---

This can be improved by doing few things:

1. `x.map(f).sequence` is equivalent to doing `x.traverse(f)`
2. We can demand that keys are non-empty upfront, and give nonempty result back too.

The latter step gives us `Reducible` instance for a collection, letting us shorten everything by doing `reduceMap`

```scala
class Foo2[F[_]: Applicative, A](find: String => F[IorNel[Error, A]]) {
  def findMultiple(keys: NonEmptyList[String]): F[IorNel[Error, NonEmptyList[A]]] = {
    keys.traverse(find).map { nelsList =>
      nelsList.reduceMap(nel => nel.map(NonEmptyList.one))
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, you can make a one-liner out of this:

```scala
keys.traverse(find).map(_.reduceMap(_.map(NonEmptyList.one)))
```

Or, you can do the non-emptiness check inside:

```scala
class Foo3[F[_]: Applicative, A](find: String => F[IorNel[Error, A]]) {
  def findMultiple(keys: List[String]): F[IorNel[Error, List[A]]] = {
    NonEmptyList.fromList(keys)
      .map(_.traverse(find).map { _.reduceMap(_.map(List(_))) })
      .getOrElse(List.empty[A].rightIor.pure[F])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ior is a good choice for warning accumulation, that is errors and a successful value. But, as mentioned by Oleg Pyzhcov, `Ior.Left` case is short-circuiting. This example illustrates it:

```scala
scala> val shortCircuitingErrors = List(
  Ior.leftNec("error1"),
  Ior.bothNec("warning2", 2),
  Ior.bothNec("warning3", 3)
).sequence

shortCircuitingErrors: Ior[Nec[String], List[Int]]] = Left(Chain(error1))
```

One way to accumulate both errors and successes is to convert all your `Left` cases into `Both`. One approach is using `Option` as right type and converting `Left(errs)` values into `Both(errs, None)`. After calling `.traverse`, you end up with `optList: List[Option]` on the right side and you can flatten it with `optList.flatMap(_.toList)` to filter out `None` values.

```scala
class Error
class KeyValue

def find(key: String): Ior[Nel[Error], KeyValue] = ???

def findMultiple(keys: List[String]): Ior[Nel[Error], List[KeyValue]] =
  keys
    .traverse { k =>
      val ior = find(k)
      ior.putRight(ior.right)
    }
    .map(_.flatMap(_.toList))
```

Or more succinctly:

```scala
def findMultiple(keys: List[String]): Ior[Nel[Error], List[KeyValue]] =
  keys.flatTraverse { k =>
    val ior = find(k)
    ior.putRight(ior.toList) // Ior[A,B].toList: List[B]
  }
```